# cref refers to chapter instead of figure

Tags: cleveref

I want to cref to a figure but somehow it  gives the chapter the figure is in instead of the figure number. The code I used is written down below:

```
From which it follows that the vector $\mathbf{\psi}$ has only two independent components as shown in \cref{eq:hhd.13} In \cref{fig:hhd.1} a wave propagating in the x-z plane shown, with a in-plane shearwave SV and an anti-plane shearwave SH.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:hhd.13}

\frac{\delta \psi_y}{\delta y}=-\left(\frac{\delta \psi_x}{\delta x}+\frac{\delta \psi_z}{\delta z}\right)

\end{equation}

\begin{figure}\label{fig:hhd.1}

\includegraphics[scale=3]{./Figures/PSV-SHwaves.jpg}

\caption{P-wave, vertical S-wave (SV) and horizontal S-wave (SH)}

\end{figure}
```

At the place where I refer to figure 5.1. (as the caption of the figure) describes, latex prints chapter 5.

Comment: This is really a FAQ. Move the `\label` after the `\caption`.

Comment: Found out what the problem was, package hyperref is used also in the document what cause the problem

Comment: @TimoMolenkamp: The real problem seems to be what Sergei mentioned already. Of course, `hyperref`should be loaded before `cleveref` here!